# How to quit a Ruby on Raily server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wash-out

Inside a test environment I am using the `wash_out` GEM within a Ruby on Rails server to run a SOAP service that serves as a Proxy between two different transfer protocols.

At the end of the test run, I would like to quit the Rails server with a dedicated SOAP request.

So I implemented such a request and called inside the request exit(0). But it seems to me that exit and abort functions are hooked away because of security or other reasons.

One might argue that terminating the service within a request is a little bit harsh, but at that point I do not care how the service gets terminated. Since it does not hold any state.

I would like to avoid to patch the Rails sources so that it is later easier to update the GEMSs.

Edit:

The server is running (unfortunately) on Windows.

Comment: SOAP rails server running on windows. I need to sit down for that. :P

Comment: What testing framework do you use? How do you start the test server?

Comment: We use TestComplete by SmartBear for UI tests. This "talks" only SOAP and must be "proxied" to an internal API based on XMLRPC

Answer (score 0):

You could execute shell script and kill running rails process. For example if you running service on unicorn you could do something like

```
def exit_app
  %x(kill -9 $(cat tmp/pids/unicorn.pid))
end
```